# Only fire event after last TreeViewItem datasource has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-handling, treeview

I have a TreeView in my View that is databound to a list of root `Node`s in my ViewModel. Those root `Node`s can have child `Nodes`. All nodes are of the same type and have the property `IsSelected` that is bound to the `IsChecked` dependency property of a `CheckBox` that's contained in the respective `TreeViewItem`. That `CheckBox` has set `IsThreeState` to `false`.

```
public class Node : PropertyChangedBase, INode
{
    private bool? _isSelected;
    private IList<INode> _nodes;
    private INode _parent;

    public Node()
    { }

    public bool? IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_SetField(ref _isSelected, value))
            {
                _OnIsSelectedChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public IList<INode> Nodes
    {
        get { return _nodes; }
        set { _SetField(ref _nodes, value); }
    }
    public INode Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set { _SetField(ref _parent, value); }
    }

    private void _OnIsSelectedChanged()
    {
        if (IsSelected.HasValue)
        {
            if (IsSelected.Value)
            {
                if (Parent != null)
                {
                    // Set IsSelected on all parenting nodes to:
                    //  - true, if all of their immediate child packages have been selected
                    //  - null, else
                }

                if (Nodes != null && Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Prevent running this method again by circumventing setting the property
                    _SetField(ref _isSelected, null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Parent != null)
                {
                    // Set IsSelected of the parent to null
                }

                if (Nodes != null)
                {
                    // Set IsSelected = false on all child nodes
                }
            }
        }
        else if (Parent != null)
        {
            // Set IsSelected on all parenting nodes to:
            //  - true, if all of their immediate child packages have been selected
            //  - null, else
        }
    }
}
```

`PropertyChangedBase` is a base class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It's been designed after [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316417/2675609). If the set value actually changes, `_SetField(ref object, object)` returns `true` and notifies about the property change.

If the user clicks a CheckBox, that change should propagate the parent node's (up to the root node) `IsSelected` property and to the child node's `IsSelected` property, too. After the propagation of all Properties finished, I want to fire an event. But only when no further node will be changed. I then want to do something in the ViewModel, that takes some time, so it would be bad performance-wise if the event would fire with each changed property.

The behaviour should be the following:

- If a node's `IsSelected` gets set to `true` or `null`, the parent node's `IsSelected` gets set to `null` if not all of the node's sibling's `IsSelected` are set to `true` or `null` (what then propagates up the tree).
- If a node's `IsSelected` gets set to `true` or `null`, the parent node's `IsSelected` gets set to `true` if all of the node's sibling's `IsSelected` are set to `true` or `null` (what then propagates up the tree).
- If a node's `IsSelected` gets set to `false`, all of its immediate child node's `IsSelected` get set to `false`, too (what then propagates down the tree).
- A node set to `null` means that not all of its immediate child nodes have been selected.

**So how can I achieve firing the PropertyChanged event (or another I'd implement) only after the last node has been changed?**

Comment: The simplest pseudocode I can think of to explain the concept of what you want to achieve is: doStuffRecursive(); fireEvent();. The trouble is I can't think of a way to "detect" whenStuffRecursiveFinished. I would have thought of some sort of count (know how many nodes you are supposed to load for a given request) that you decrement with Interlocked.Decrement() and when 0. But I believe this would get quite complicated fast and there are better ways through WPF mechanisms

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea of course. DoStuffRecursive then fireEvent. If I have a public method on my `Node` that sets `IsSelected` without calling `_OnIsSelectedChanged`, I can change all nodes in one method firing the event afterwards. I'd have to lock, though, to prevent calling `_OnIsSelectedChanged` twice at the same time. I'll try that.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea thank you for the inspiration. I ended up doing exactly this: raise `IsSelectedChangedPropagationStarted`, perform the propagation, raise `IsSelectedChangedPropagationCompleted`. Works like a charme. I can't believe, I didn't came up with this by myself. Sometimes you just need a little push in the right direction. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you can, add a more complete answer, it might be helpful for other people in the future! Once gain, congratulations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing what [Alexandru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8695782/alexandru-clon%C8%9Bea) suggested.

I introduced two events `IsSelectedChangedPropagationStarted` & `IsSelectedChangedPropagationCompleted` the first being raised before handling the selection and the latter being raised upon completion. The class looks similar to this now:

```
public class Node : PropertyChangedBase, INode
{
    // #### Attributes
    private bool? _isSelected;
    private IList<INode> _nodes;
    private INode _parent;

    // #### Constructor
    public Node()
    { }

    // #### Properties
    public bool? IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_SetField(ref _isSelected, value))
            {
                _OnIsSelectedChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public IList<INode> Nodes
    {
        get { return _nodes; }
        set { _SetField(ref _nodes, value); }
    }
    public INode Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set { _SetField(ref _parent, value); }
    }

    // #### Events
    public event EventHandler IsSelectedChangedPropagationStarted;
    public event EventHandler IsSelectedChangedPropagationCompleted;

    // #### Instance Methods
    private void _OnIsSelectedChanged()
    {
        IsSelectedChangedPropagationStarted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        if (IsSelected.HasValue)
        {
            if (IsSelected.Value)
            {
                RecursivelySetAllParents();

                if (Nodes != null && Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Prevent running this method again by circumventing setting the property
                    _SetField(ref _isSelected, null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Parent != null)
                {
                    // Set IsSelected of the parent to null
                }

                RecursivelySetAllChildren();
            }
        }
        else if (Parent != null)
        {
            // Set IsSelected on all parenting nodes to:
            //  - true, if all of their immediate child packages have been selected
            //  - null, else
        }

        IsSelectedChangedPropagationCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

By implementing custom `EventArgs` I could also tell the listeners if something at all has changed so they can act accordingly.